# What VS magic provides ".js.bundle" functionality to combine JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, bundle

I am using Durandal in my project and it comes with a "vendor.js.bundle" file that looks similar to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bundle minify="true" runOnBuild="true">
  <file>/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js</file>
  <file>/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js</file>
  <!-- snip -->
</bundle>
```

I can tell it is some form of automated file to assist in generation of "vendor.js", but I have been unable to find *what* actually does this building stage - much less, how to get it to "just work" in my environment.

I downloaded the Web Essentials extension, but the magic doesn't seem to originate from within there (or is this only a feature of the VS 2012 version?) and my search-foo has been failing.

Comment: It's not a feature of VS, but a feature of ASP.NET MVC 4: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: @Dai In my case the vendor.js file seems to have been generated statically first by some tool (it leaves some annotation lines) - that article appears to be dynamic bundling and, while useful, not really what I'm looking for. I guess it might not even be a VS tool ..

Comment: @Dai no it is not. I've done this in ASP.NET web form projects as well

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a feature of Visual Studio Extension "Web Essentials".

Select at least two javascript files in your project and right click them and go to Web Essentials --> Create JavaScript bundle file.

[image]

It will bundle your javascript files and create a minified version of the bundle as well. You can do this to CSS files as well.